# How to reset all environment variables?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, unset, linux-mint

I want to do :

```
env | egrep -o '^\w+=' | unset
```

The problem is that :

```
env | egrep -o '^\w+='
```

prints things like (notice the *equal* sign) :

> XDG_VTNR=
>   LC_PAPER=
>   SSH_AGENT_PID=
>   KDE_MULTIHEAD=
>   LC_ADDRESS=
>   XDG_SESSION_ID=

How do I extract just the variable names so I can unset them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need something more like this:

```
for i in `env | sed 's/=.*//'` ; do
    unset $i
done
```

Note, however, this will probably do more things than you want.  EG, it'll unset your path too!